# Docker is running but I cannot access localhost - Flask application

Tags: docker, flask

I built I Flask application and I am trying to make it run on a Docker file.

I run two commands:

1)

```
docker build -t my-api-docker:latest .
```

2)

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 my-api-docker
```

Both are run without errors and the output on terminal is the classic Flask:

```
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

**HOWEVER**

If I visit: `http://localhost:5000` if show that:

> > The page is not working

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask==1.1.1
requests==2.20.1
pandas==0.23.4
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "flask", "run" ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should not bind with container localhost i.e

> Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

change the CMD in Dockerfile

```
CMD [ "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0" ]
```

or

```
CMD ["python3", "-m", "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

or replace the inside your code

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0').
```